# AutoResizeTextView does not resize after other Views are hidden (View.GONE)

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-canvas, visibility

**Context**:

I have two [AutoResizeTextViews](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView/tree/master/AutoFitTextViewLibrary/src/com/lb/auto_fit_textview) inside a LinearLayout. I would like to have the first one about 1/3 of the size of the second one, and both as large as possible. Therefore I use layout_weight=1 and layout_weight=3 as can be seen in the XML code below.

**Problem**:

When I hide other TextViews in the View of the Fragment (stored as mView), using:

```
textView7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
(..many more to GONE..)
```

more space gets available for the LinearLayout, and so I expect the AutoResizeTextViews to grow. However the two AutoResizeTextViews do not grow, and seem to keep their canvas size. They are moved to align to the new 1/3 ratio of the LinearLayout, so there really is space inside the LinearLayout.

When the Activity and the View is restarted upon device reorientation (I do not retain the Fragment) they DO change as expected, apparently the canvas is redrawn correctly then. How can I make the AutoResizeTextView to be redrawn correctly without have to turn the device?

**Already tried**:

```
mView.forceLayout();
mView.refreshDrawableState();
mView.requestLayout();
mView.invalidate();
linearLayoutAutoFit.invalidate();
tvTimer.invalidate();
tvTimer.setTextsize(999);
```

is all not working, the Text is not adjusted to the new size.

**XML code**:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAutoFit"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/viewline2"
    android:layout_below="@id/progressBar3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    >

    <AutoResizeTextView
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/Ready"
        android:id="@+id/textViewAction"
        android:textSize="999sp"
        android:textColor="#ADFF2F"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <AutoResizeTextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="@string/init_time"
        android:textSize="999sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer by Kastriot was very close, and also part of the solution, I found the solution today by testing the values inside the AutoResizableTextView class with Log outputs. The mistake I made was that I also had

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Because of that, upon layout change, the width of the AutoResizableTextView was not adjusted! As a consequence, the text could not grow in size. Therefore the setting for the width should be:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

such that the width of the AutoResizableTextView is large enough to fit a larger text.

Answer (score 0):

instead :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

type :

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that, it solved an issue with the layout_weight. However, it does not solve the problem described...